# Does guice module work in Play framework unittest?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have some Play framework unit tests and I can't seem to inject Guice module..

Does Guice module works in the scope of unit test ?

Play 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

"The guice module contains a bunch of tests (see modules/guice-1.2/tests), which are picked up in the classpath, but aren't really intended to be."(This comment belongs to Mark Piper)

A solution would be running

**play deps --forProd**

before starting play in test mode.